# How to find an element in a list inside a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, search, dictionary

I have a problem in developing a Python code. I have to find an element in a list: the list is the value of a dictionary.

For example:

```
d={0:[7,2,3],1:[4,5,6],2:[0,7,8]}
```

I have to verify if an element, for example the `2` as element-value of the key `0`, has also the `0` value as the `2` key. In the example is verified, but it isn't true if I search for the `1` value in `0` key and vice versa. How I can develop a search like these ones?

Answer (score 1):

```
2 in d[0] and 0 in d[2]
```

or if you want to wrap it in a function

```
def check2NumbersInDict(n1, n2, dict):
    return (n1 in dict[n2] and n2 in dict[n1])
```

Not sure if this is what you were asking for but it's what I could gather

Comment: Yes, but I had to do this operation for all the element in the list so I'll try with two nested for-loops. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I would do as follows:

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    if any([d.get(val) for val in value]):
        print "{} is OK".format(key)
```